# Wrong Percentage of Subtotal

Tags: tableau-api

I'm having an issue with tables calculations in tableau. I've got sales per manager and the target. I wanna have a calculation of the targets achievement. 
That's what my data looks like and the percentage I wanna get:

[image]

Unfortunately, Tableau sums up the percentage and gives me the following results:

[image]

Target columns is a calculated field. E.g.

```
IF [Manager Name] =    "Manager 1" THEN "190000"
```

The % columns is a calculated field and calculated as the following:

```
 FLOAT([Profit])  / FLOAT([Target])
```

I tried to play with Table Calculations but it never worked.

Comment: Do you have one row per Manager in your dataset? or many? (i.e. what is the level of detail in your dataset). That info impacts your choice of calculation options.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that a table calculation would help solve your issue.  As you have the % field now, Tableau is just summing the field for each manager to get your subtotal.  To get Tableau to calculate the subtotal smartly, as you would expect, you need to modify your % field formula.

**Your way:** Calculate Percentage for each manager and then SUM for subtotal

**Fixed Way:** Indicate to Tableau that you want the field to be calculated by summing all profit values first in the partition (Location) and then divide to get the percentage. In this case (330000/532000).

You can modify your % field to look something like the following:

```
WINDOW_SUM(FLOAT(SUM([Profit])))/WINDOW_SUM(FLOAT(SUM([Target])))
```

See the below thread for some more information on how the windowing functions can help with aggregate calculations
https://community.tableau.com/thread/200670

Comment: This formal gave me 0.01% in the whole column over all the managers and locations

Comment: @hamsy Try playing around with the table calculation compute using options.  It will vary depending on what dimensions you have, but you can try something like "Pane Down" based on the image you showed.